# why the result is different between running python interpreter and python code?

Tags: python, floating-point

I made a simple code on python interpreter and run it.

```
Python 3.5.3 (v3.5.3:1880cb95a742, Jan 16 2017, 16:02:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.array([0,1])
>>> w=np.array([0.5,0.5])
>>> b=-0.7
>>> np.sum(w*x)+b
-0.19999999999999996
```

the result -0.19999999999999996 is weird. I think.... it is caused by IEEE 754 rule. But when I try to run almost same code by file, result is a lot different.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0,1])
w = np.array([0.5,0.5])
b = -0.7
print(np.sum(w * x) + b)
```

the result is "-0.2". IEEE 754 rule does not affect the result.

what is the difference between file based running and interpreter based running?

Comment: have you tried `print(np.sum(w*x)+b)` from your interpreter? printing isn't the same as asking the interpreter to represent it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is due to how the interpreter displays output.

The `print` function will try to use an object's `__str__` method, but the interpreter will use an object's `__repr__`.

If, in the interpreter you wrote:

```
...
z = np.sum(w*x)+b
print(z)
```

(which is what you're doing in your code) you'd see `-0.2`.

Similarly, if in your code you wrote:

```
print(repr(np.sum(w * x) + b))
```

(which is what you're doing in the interpreter) you'd see `-0.19999999999999996`

Comment: I didn't know this before. Awesome explanation!

Comment: can you explain how IEEE754 rule didn't work in print()?

Comment: @LaserCho -- I'm not sure what you mean -- the decision to implement `numpy64.float`'s `__repr__` and `__str__` differently is numpy's, really (Python used to do this for `float`s but has since unified them).

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference lies in the fact that you use `print()` for your file based code, which converts the number, while in the interpreter's case, you don't use `print()`, but rather ask the interpreter to show the result.